# Nginx change root directory if specific query_string is specified in config

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want to change change root directory if specific `query_string` is given in config,

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.test.com;

if ( $query_string = "abc") {
    set $variable "abc";
    }
if ( $query_string = "def") {
    set $variable "def";
    }

if ( $query_string = "") {
    set $variable "";
    }

set $site_root /var/data/www/$variable;
```

if i hit url `http://www.test.com/?abc` then it should point root to this directory `/var/data/www/abc` and if i hit this url `http://www.test.com/def?` root should be `/var/data/www/def` and if no `query_string` is passed then root dir should be `/var/data/www` practically  it is pointing to no `query_string` condition.

any idea how can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Config which i mentioned in my question was correct just css was not loading from above web root dir so i added this config for css to solve issue,

```
location ~* /(css)/ {
    root  /var/data/www/$variable;
    }
```